# Adding a model parameters to a scatterplot with ggscatter in R

Tags: r

I am trying to add the model parameters of linear regression with following R code:

```
 ggscatter(data, x = "ULS", y = "TLS", add = "reg.line", conf.int = TRUE, add.params = list(color = "blue",
                                                                                           fill = "lightgray")) +
  stat_cor(label.x = 1, label.y = 1, label.x.npc = "centre", label.y.npc = "top") +
  stat_regline_equation(label.x = 1, label.y = 1, label.x.npc = "centre", label.y.npc = "top")
```

But, equation, R2 and p value are on far right of the plot and are not readable, how do I put them to the middle top?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ideas. Both play with `label.x` and `hjust`.

First solution: Setting `stat_cor` in the center but right-justified and putting the other stat next to it.

```
ggscatter(data, x = "ULS", y = "TLS", add = "reg.line", 
          conf.int = TRUE, add.params = list(color = "blue",
                                                      fill = "lightgray")) +
  stat_cor(label.x = .5, label.y.npc = "top", hjust = 1) +
  stat_regline_equation(label.x = .55, label.y.npc = "top")
```

Second solution: Center both stats to the same spot and adjust both with `hjust`

```
ggscatter(data, x = "ULS", y = "TLS", add = "reg.line", 
          conf.int = TRUE, add.params = list(color = "blue",
                                             fill = "lightgray")) +
  stat_cor(label.x.npc ="center", label.y.npc = "top", hjust = 1) +
  stat_regline_equation(label.x.npc =  "center", label.y.npc = "top", hjust = -.1)
```